# HttpClient - detect Content-Type

Tags: c#, .net, content-type, dotnet-httpclient

I need to detect a type of content located on specific URL. So I created a method to get the Content-Type of response. For small files and HTML pages it works without problems, but if URL points to a big file, request takes a long time - it fetches entire content (file) on background. So, it is possible to cancel request and return result immediately after teh `Content-Type` header is received?

**My current implementation:**

```
    public async static Task<string> GetContentType(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would imagine the functionality in that question is dependant on the server sending the response though. It may not honour the request and just send you everything anyway

Comment: You cannot do this with `HttpClient`, but `WebHttpRequest` does allow you to.

Comment: WebException cannot handle all the possible execptions of the GetAsync method. You should consider a broader catch. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298646.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 .

Comment: @Richard See the answers here. What's wrong with their use of HttpClient? Also, if nothing's wrong, then this question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @YamMarcovic Firstly it is a duplicate: getting only the headers, and thus extracting the `Content-Type` is what the other Q asks. Secondly I checked `HttpClient` for a `Get` overload that took an HTTP method parameter (but missed there is a different method that does). In any case the other Q answers this question (even if it does use a different type).

Comment: @Richard - my question is not a duplicate... I'm using the HttpClient class

Comment: @Richard The question, even in its title, deals with the HttpClient class. By your reasoning, you might as well have marked it as a duplicate since there's an answer with an equivalent Python implementation.

Comment: @YamMarcovic By that argument if a question has a title that names completely the wrong approach to a problem all answers must stick with the wrong approach? I am unmoved; if you have a real problem with this the right place to object is on meta.

Comment: @Richard The question's title asks about a specific class (which is a correct one to use). The content deals with that same class. How do we get from that to saying that a  question dealing with another class entirely is a duplicate?

Comment: @YamMarcovic (This will be my last comment: see end of my previous comment.) Because it answers the "how do I just get the headers on a HTTP request" question. Just because the Q has a starting point for a solution does not mean it is the only starting point. Yes `HttpCliient` is a possible approach; but so is `HttpWebRequest`. (Don't forget there are many Q's on [SO] failing into the "X Y Problem".)

Comment: I agree with Yam, as long as this question is "HttpClient - detect Content-Type", this is not a duplicate. I'm migrating from WebClient to HttpClient, so the redirection to the WebClient solution did not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

Since not all servers respond to the HEAD request as expected, you can also use this overload of [GetAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298645.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method so that the method returns immediately after headers are received if you use [HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.web.http.httpcompletionoption.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as second argument.

> An HTTP completion option value that indicates when the operation
>   should be considered completed.

ResponseHeadersRead from MSDN:

> The operation should complete as soon as a response is available and
>   headers are read. The content is not read yet.

Then you can dispose the client if you need to.

```
// Send request to get headers
 response = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

// Check status code
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
  // Error...
}

// Get Content Headers
HttpContentHeaderCollection contentHeaders = response.Content.Headers;


// Make decision and dispose client if you wish
if (...) {
   client.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: "Since not all servers respond to the HEAD request as expected" -- References? It's a big deal since you'll be needlessly using up bandwidth for both you and the server.

Comment: @YamMarcovic  I'd said that based on experience.

Answer (score 4):

Now how about

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(
  new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url)
);
```

Comment: @Liam From RFC 2616, "9.4 HEAD

The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response"

Comment: So what your getting at is the `HttpMethod.Head` bit. You didn't explain that very well....

Comment: @Liam It's a short and self-explanatory piece of code.

Comment: Depending on the implementation on the web-server, it might not support `HEAD`. A fallback on `GET` is recommended.

Comment: @diemaus Do you know of a common one that actually doesn't support HEAD?

Comment: Some APIs I've worked with over the years have not been able to abide to the `HEAD` spec.

Comment: @diemaus Interesting, though I wonder if the extra code is needed in this case. At any rate, an approach of using it as a fallback is much better than being the default, since that way you're giving both you and the server the opportunity to save wasted bandwidth.

Comment: @YamMarcovic It certainly depends on the implementation. If it's implemented towards a web-service which is *known* to abide by the `HEAD`-spec, then by all means; a fallback is not needed. No bandwidth needs to be wasted here though, since you check the response before doing the `GET`-request.